# SendGrid event API in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sendgrid

I am using SendGrid API for my sending mails and now i want to learn what event is used with email?

Please refer to [this site](http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/api/event-api/)

Like is it delivered, processed, open, etc... I also would like to get that status in my database table.

So does anyone know what kind of integration I need to do or what kind of coding I need to apply.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work at SendGrid

To get the events that happen, you would enable the Event Notification app within the dashboard (or enable it using the settings API calls, http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/api/web-api/webapifilters/)

To start, you'd provide a URL which we will POST information to about events that happen regarding messages. Current event list is:

- we processed the message
- the message was dropped
- message was deferred (we'll try again later)
- message was delivered
- message bounced from ISP/ESP
- message was opened
- a link in the message was clicked
- a recipient unsubscribed
- a user reported the message as spam.